# Customised settings no longer marking errors and problems

Tags: android, android-studio

Until yesterday I had no problem with android studio and it's worked fine but today I have some problems with it .

For example, in my code I write " Strng s; ", as you can see I have wrong spelled the String, and android studio not tell me that this line is wrong.

or by default when you write code and use some libraries like Log or Dialog, android studio automatically import the necessary lib files but mine, it doesn't include them and also it does not mark it and tells me that I need to include the library.

so It make the coding very hard and full of problems .

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Did you update something? Install a custom plugin or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

Go **File -> Settings**

If you go into Code Completion, Auto Import and PostFix Completion along with setting your Code Style settings you have a lot of flexibility in what you choose the ide to show you.

[image]

In terms of you losing your settings, a file may have been deleted or over written, it's hard to say, it's something you learn to keep track of with your ides. Make a note of which folder your settings are saved to.

Comment: @ thanks for reply , It's all set but still the same,

Comment: thanks for rely , something very interesting , in the same project some of the activities has this problem but some of them not , Why is that ?

Comment: it's windows 7 , ram 6 - cpu cor i 4